# Why wont all of this string print?

Tags: php, string, wordpress, concatenation

I am just trying to generate a path with something like :

```
$PhotoName = the_title(); 
$DestinationFile = 'temp/watermarked/';
$DestinationFile .= $PhotoName;
$DestinationFile .= '.jpg';
```

`the_title();` is a Wordpress function that gets the title of the post.  If I `echo` just `$PhotoName` I see the name of the post as suspected.  However if I `echo $DestinationFile` it will never print that part of the string so I would see something like `temp/watermarked/.jpg`, it never prints `$PhotoName` as part of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `false` as the third parameter to get it to return the page title to you.

```
$PhotoName = the_title('', '', false);
```

See the [WordPress reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) for more details.

Comment: You're correct. I misread it when I googled it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Alternatively, [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)

Answer (score 0):

`the_title()` is a template tag that must be run within the loop.  The title applies filters and prints the title to the screen.

Use `get_the_title()` to return the value in php.

When using a foreach loop with `get_posts()` use `$post->post_title` to get the value.  If you want the filters applied: `apply_filters( 'the_title', $post->post_title );`